# What can I do with call.getSubresourceUris() and call.getUri() in Twilio

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api

In a typicall Twilio call code like this:

```
CallCreator callCreator = Call.creator(to, from, twiml);
Call call = callCreator.create();
```

'call' object contains some information. 
In concrete I want to know, and will appreciate a sample code, that show me what can I do with this URLs:

```
subresourceUris={
    notifications=/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Calls/CAZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ/Notifications.json
    recordings=/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Calls/CAZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ/Recordings.json
    feedback=/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Calls/CAZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ/Feedback.json
    feedback_summaries=/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Calls/FeedbackSummary.json
    }
uri=/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Calls/CAZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ.json
```

Nothing found about it in Twilio DOC.